# Pyramid route matching and query parameters

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a Pyramid web service, and code samples are as follows:

View declaration:

```
@view_config(route_name="services/Prices/GetByTicker/")
def GET(request):
    ticker = request.GET('ticker')
    startDate = request.GET('startDate')
    endDate = request.GET('endDate')
    period = request.GET('period')
```

Routing:

```
config.add_route('services/Prices/GetByTicker/', 'services/Prices/GetByTicker/{ticker}/{startDate}/{endDate}/{period}')
```

Now I know this is all screwed up but I don't know what the convention is for Pyramid. At the moment this works inasmuch as the request gets routed to the view successfully, but then I get a "Dictionary object not callable" exception.

The URL looks horrible:

@root/services/Prices/GetByTicker/ticker=APPL/startDate=19981212/endDate=20121231/period=d

Ideally I would like to be able to use a URL something like:

@root/services/Prices/GetByTicker/?ticker=APPL&startDate=19981212&endDate=20121231&period=d

Any Pyramid bods out there willing to take five minutes to explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

from you sample code, i think you use the [URL Dispatch](http://pylons.readthedocs.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#urldispatch-chapter)

so it should be like this

```
config.add_route('services/Prices/GetByTicker/', 'services/Prices/GetByTicker/')
```

then the URL like:
@root/services/Prices/GetByTicker/?ticker=APPL&startDate=19981212&endDate=20121231&period=d
will match it

--edit--
you don't have to use a name like "services/Prices/GetByTicker" for route_name,and you can get the GET params use `request.params['key']`
View declaration:

```
@view_config(route_name="services_Prices_GetByTicker")
def services_Prices_GetByTicker(request):
    ticker = request.params['ticker']
    startDate = request.params['startDate']
    endDate = request.params['endDate']
    period = request.params['period']
```

Routing:

```
config.add_route('services_Prices_GetByTicker', 'services/Prices/GetByTicker/')
```

Comment: Thank you. Precisely what I was looking for. It's always the simple answer you can't find from the documentation...

Answer (score 5):

The query string is turned into the `request.GET` dictionary. You are using parenthesis to call the dictionary instead of accessing items via the brackets. For a url such as

> @root/services/Prices/GetByTicker/?ticker=APPL&startDate=19981212&endDate=20121231&period=d

```
request.GET['ticker'] # -> 'APPL' or an exception if not available
request.GET.get('ticker') # -> 'APPL' or None if not available
request.GET.get('ticker', 'foo') # -> 'APPL' or 'foo' if not available
request.GET.getall('ticker') # -> ['APPL'] or [] if not available
```

The last option is useful if you expect `ticker` to be supplied multiple times.

`request.params` is a combination of `request.GET` and `request.POST` where the latter is a dictionary representing the request's body in a form upload.

Anyway, the answer is that `request.GET('ticker')` syntactically is not one of the options I mentioned, stop doing it. :-)

Comment: I was initially misled by some sample code I found. A reminder never to go that route. 

On the multiple-ticker question. How would such a request be formed? 

Would you pass in ticker=AAPL&ticker=MSFT?

Or ticker=[AAPL, MSFT]